# C++ settings return value mutex

Tags: c++, return, copy, settings, mutex

In my application running on an ESP32 using FreeRTOS, I've implemented a setting class responsible for storing various settings. I'm currently concerned about the thread safety of this class, specifically regarding the 'Get' method.

Could someone please review my implementation and confirm whether it is correct and thread-safe? I have doubts about whether 'copy' is always a true copy, especially when the setting type is a string or an object.

```
template<typename T>
class Setting : public ISetting
{
    Mutex& mutex;
    T Value;

public:
    Setting(Mutex& mutex, const T& defaultValue)
        : mutex(mutex)
        , Value(defaultValue)
    {
    }

    void Set(const T& value)
    {
        mutex.Take();
        Value = value; // Assign the new value to the setting
        mutex.Give();
    }

    T Get()
    {
        T copy;
        mutex.Take();
        copy = Value;
        mutex.Give();
        return copy;
    }

    void Accept(ISettingVisitor* handler)
    {
        handler->Visit(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: **please review** - https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you mean by 'true copy'?

Comment: So, is the string, for example, actually copied in memory? If it is by reference the mutex won't work like this.

Comment: If `T` is a concrete non-reference type (for example, but not limited to, `int`, `std::string`, etc) then you create a "true copy". For a *deep* copy it requires `T` to have actual copy-semantics either through the rule of three or the rule of zero.

Comment: You probably mean deep copy. I think it should get copied in memory. It will probably call `std::string& operator=(const std::string&)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get()` is thread-safe in the sense that the execution of the copy assignment operator for `T` is only done by one thread concurrently. However, it's not safe at large.

#### Exception Safety

`Take()` and `Give()` are really unusual names for locking/unlocking; for `std::mutex` these are called `.lock()` and `.unlock()`.
If they were called like that, you could use `std::scoped_lock` instead of manually locking/unlocking:

```cpp
void Set(const T& value)
{
    std::scoped_lock lock{mutex}; // or std::lock_guard before C++17
    Value = value;
}

T Get()
{
    std::scoped_lock lock{mutex}; // or std::lock_guard before C++17
    return Value;
}
```

Or alternatively, this could use `std::experimental::scope_exit` or some other way to unlock the mutex in the destructor.

In any case, it's **really important** that you unlock the mutex in a destructor because that makes exception safety easy. `mutex` in your code is **never unlocked** if `copy = Value` throws an exception, and a copy assignment operator could reasonably do that. The same issues apply to `Set()`.

#### Unsafe if `T` has reference semantics

If `T` doesn't have value semantics, then this code still isn't *really* thread-safe. For example, if `T = std::span`, then the caller could modify the data that the span references concurrently and unsafely. Copying a `std::span` is what you would call a "shallow copy"; it doesn't copy the underlying data ("deep copy").

However, that's not something that you can fix. There is no way to check what the semantics of a given type are. It's the responsibility of the user of `Setting` to ensure overall safe usage. The responsibility of `Setting` is only to thread-safely get and set some value.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed anwser. I meight need to clarify my useage of mutex. I am running this code on the ESP32 and the mutex class is a wrapper around the freertos mutex. That's why I use the give and take since these names are also used in the freertos api.

The scoped lock is quite simple to make aswell, So I meight do that. It will fix the exception safety problem.

Comment: I see that cpp mutexes are supported, it meight be better to stick to those.
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/cplusplus.html#multithreading

Comment: @BasVisscher in my opinion, unless you need compatibility with pre-C++11 code, it's better to just use the standard versions instead of relying on third-party library features.